# Loading multiple versions of a javascript library, dynamically and asynchronously

Tags: javascript, dom, jsonp, requirejs, amd

I have a number of different versions of a javascript libraries to load dynamically.

For example, let's say that I want to load multiple versions of the foo library. I have:

```
foo-0.1.js
foo-0.2.js
```

Foo is not an AMD-compliant library and it hasn't a no-conflict mode. It is a third-part library of which I have no control. It just do something along the line of:

```
window.Foo = fooFunction;
```

These library version are loaded asynchronously and dynamically in a plugin scenario. Loading is actually done by requirejs, but it's not important. Let's just say that the content of the functions is downloaded and executed.

Let's say we have a MODULE_1 plugin that needs foo-0.1, and a MODULE_2 plugin that needs foo-0.2.

When requested by the user (for example by clicking on its name), MODULE_1 is initialized and loads foo-0.1. It sets up an user interface (a canvas) and waits for user input. The window.foo object now points to version 0.1.

Then, the user request MODULE_2, which is initialized and starts to load foo-0.2, then sets up its canvas and waits for user input. Now window.foo is overwritten and points to foo-0.2.

Finally, the user clicks on the user interface of MODULE_1, which reacts to the situation and tries do do something. But window.foo is pointing to foo-0.2 object, which is incompatible with MODULE_1, and it crashes miserably.

What I would like is to store foo-0.1 in an object and foo-0.2 in another.
Is there some way to change the window object when loading foo-0.1 and foo-0.2?

PS. I don't think that this will work:

```
/* MODULE_1 */
// load foo-0.1
// when ready:
var foo-0.1 = window.foo

/* MODULE_1 */
// load foo-0.2
// when ready:
var foo-0.2 = window.foo
```

Because I cant' be sure that the ready event of one of the two will load before the ready event of the other (am I right?)

PPS: I'm well-aware of [RequireJs multiversion support](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion), but it won't work unless the loaded libraries are AMD-compliant.

Comment: Can't you just wrap that foo library into an AMD?

Comment: @Bergi: It is a third-part library of which I have no control, as I wrote in the question.

Comment: What makes you think that multiversion support does not work with shims?

Comment: @zeroflagL "The shim config only sets up code relationships. To load modules that are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is needed. Setting shim by itself does not trigger code to load".

This means that shim scripts will be loaded with require(), get executed and update window.foo normally. What makes you think the contrary?

Comment: I did not state something different. Multiversion support is just different configs. You can set up different shims for each config and load them. You wrote that you already load them with require.js. If you want to use them in parallel you could for instance use an init function for the shim where you assign Window.Foo to another variable (if Window.Foo is set by your foo.js)

Comment: Can you put this in answer form? I'm not sure on how a "init function for the shim" looks like, maybe with some code it'll all be clear.